# C++ Inheritance "toString"

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, mingw

I have 2 c++ classes where one is a base class of the other (public inheritance). I have the << operator overload done in both. What I want is to use << of the sub class with the << of the base class.

It's that possible?

I mean, imagine that base class << overload print's "Hi, my name is Rui" and I want that sub class << overload prints "Hi, my name is Rui\nIt's sunny today".

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Did you meant to something like this?

(to use Base class virtual function from the overlapped Sub class function)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Base{
public:
   virtual string toString()const{
      return string("Hi, my name is Rui");
   }
};

class Sub: public Base{
public:
   virtual string toString()const{
      return Base::toString() + string("\nIt's sunny today");
   }
};

//this should work for both Base and Sub 
ostream& operator <<(ostream& stream, const Base& b){
   return stream<<b.toString();
}

int main(){
    Base b;
    Sub s;

    cout<<"Base print:"<<endl<<b<<endl;

    cout<<"Sub print:"<<endl<<s<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
Base print:
Hi, my name is Rui
Sub print:
Hi, my name is Rui
It's sunny today
```

Comment: Yes, something like that.. I'm a java guy so the fact of not having something like that in c++ is confusing xD

Comment: I added `operator<<`, and `main` function, and also set the `toString()` to be const, so now it can be compiled and run as is.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by defining a virtual member function in the base class, and calling it from the `operator <<` of the base class, like this:

```
struct Base {
    virtual string show() {return "Hi, my name is Raul";}
};
struct Derived : public Base {
    virtual string show() {return "Hi, my name is Raul, and it's sunny today";}
};
ostream& operator <<(ostream& ostr, const Base& val) {
    ostr << val.show();
    return ostr;
}
```

Now the actual dispatching is done virtually, while the `operator <<` is used only to allow the operator syntax for the output (i.e. the implementation os the same for both classes, but the printing logic can be changed in a subclass simply by overriding a virtual member function).

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a virtual toString funtion :

```
class base{
    public:
    virtual string toString(){
       return string("Hi, my name is Rui"); 
    }
};

class derived:public base{
     public:
     virtual string toString(){
       return string("Hi, my name is Rui\nIt's sunny today");   
    }   
};
```

Comment: The OP wants to use the base class's toString function as part of the subclass's toString